# TypeError: Cannot read property 'splitChunks' of undefined - Webpack

Tags: webpack, config

I just replace in my **webpack.dev.config.js** the :

`new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'common', }),`

by

`new webpack.optimization.splitChunks({ name: 'common' }),`.

Now when I want to use `yarn start` in my terminal I have the issue below:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'splitChunks' of undefined`

How can I fix this please?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Fix it:
plugins:

```
[
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Code splitting'enter code here
    }),
],
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
    }
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try to do that.

Comment: Notice: Webpack version >= 4. :)))

Comment: What could it mean if I'm getting this error without using splitChunks in my code at all? It seems to be coming from next-css